# Windows 10 - Game Bar Record Screen Temporary Folder

Tags: windows-10, recording

I was recording a very important work for over an hour using micosoft's GameBar (Winkey+G) when I stopped it, it messaged me that the file could not be saved cause of hard disk space. I see that my drive's free space is less than when I stated recording. So I am wondering is that program keeps that temp file somewhere and I can recover it?

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you are recording using the Game Bar you are creating a video file of everything happening on your computer. This is going to be a very large file and there is nothing that will really change that fact.

These files will save to your profile folder under **Videos\Captures** unless you have specified otherwise.

So, your hard disk space will go down when you record your screen.

I would guess that any temp files would be inside your profile directory in the hidden **AppData\Local\Temp** folder. If you cannot find the file there, perhaps use a tool such as WinDirStat to look for large files in those directories.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The default folder for recording is empty, and I just downloaded that tool and searched inside AppData\Local\Temp\ but I there isn't  there any file remotely close to the size of my file ( like 2-2,5GB, this is how lower my hard driver space is), or 'juicy' by filename or extension..

Comment: Hmmm. And I'm having trouble finding anything specific on this. I'll keep googling because this has piqued my interest.

Comment: I am googling too, nothing so far! Thank you for your time anyway!

Comment: @music2myear What makes you think a Windows Store app (in this case, Xbox) has access to AppData\Local\Temp? They are sandboxed!

Comment: That's a good point. I'll extend my search.

Comment: It clearly has access to the output "Captures" directory. Why should it not have access to a temp directory as well?

Answer (score 0):

The folder used to record video, from the XBox Game Bar, is defined in the following registry key:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\{EDC0FE71-98D8-4F4A-B920-C8DC133CB165}**

If the value defined in this registry key isn't found, Windows will default to using your %Temp% folder.